# Jquery function consumes the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, variables

I don't quite understand what's wrong with my function that I wrote,

When I pass an array to it, eg:

```
var pvars=['health/1/1.jpg','health/1/2.jpg','health/1/3.jpg','health/1/4.jpg'];
cache_threads(pvars,1);
```

Then I end up with an empty variable, eg:

```
alert(pvars);
```

Returns an empty string.

Here is my function:

```
var cache_threads=function (arruy,quant){
    if (quant==undefined) quant=1;
var div=Math.ceil(arruy.length/quant);
var a = arruy;
while(a.length) {
    cache_bunch(a.splice(0,div));
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` and `arruy` are *the same array*.

When you `.splice` one, you'll be splicing the other one, too!

If you want a (shallow) *copy* of the array, use `.slice()`:

```
var a = arruy.slice(0);
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought of that... would you suggest any solution to it?